# How do i use multiple CXF endpoints to call a webservice in Camel?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I have two endpoints:

```
CXF_FIRST_ENDPOINT="cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint?{address=first_address}&serviceClass=com.service.class.first"
CXF_SECOND_ENDPOINT="cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint?{address=second_address}&serviceClass=com.service.class.second"
```

How do I implement two separate web service call after defining the endpoints. If I use both, and consume the endpoints using the routes, one of the endpoints will override the other and I am able to use only one. If I comment the other endpoint, Its running successfully. However I need to use both. I am using messageContentList for both the web service response:

```
MessageContentsList result = (MessageContentsList) exchange.getIn().getBody();
```

Thanks, please let me know if you need more information

---

Here is the route-definition:

```
from("direct:paymentInfo").routeId("PaymentInfo") 
    .bean(billingServiceProcessor, "processBillingPaymentRequest") 
    .to(CXF_BILLINGSERVICE_ENDPOINT)
    .bean(billingServiceProcessor, "processBillingPaymentResponse")
    .end();

from("direct:Holidays").routeId("HolidayRetrieval") 
    .bean(entityProcessor, "processHolidaysRequest") 
    .to(CXF_ENTITYSERVICE_ENDPOINT)
    .bean(entityProcessor, "processHolidaysResponse")
    .end();
```

Comment: Why don't you create two routes each listening on incoming requests from their endpoint? The current logic is refactored to a new route `from("direct:processRequest")` and each endpoint-route forwards the request via `to("direct:processRequest")` to the processingRequest route.

Comment: I did create two separate routes and created separate request-response methods for both the routes. But the endpoints are still overriding each other.

Comment: from("direct:paymentInfo").routeId("PaymentInfo")
        .bean(billingServiceProcessor, "processBillingPaymentRequest")
        .to(CXF_BILLINGSERVICE_ENDPOINT)
        .bean(billingServiceProcessor, "processBillingPaymentResponse").end();

Comment: from("direct:Holidays").routeId("HolidayRetrieval")
    .bean(entityProcessor, "processHolidaysRequest")
    .to(CXF_ENTITYSERVICE_ENDPOINT)
    .bean(entityProcessor, "processHolidaysResponse").end();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I found out that both the endpoints were using the same beanid (cxfEndpoint) that was defined in the camel-config.xml.

I defined another id cxfEndpoint1 in camel-config.xml and used it to my endpoint and that solved the problem. Both the web-service calls are working fine without hassles.

```
<bean id="cxfEndpoint" class="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint" />
<bean id="cxfEndpoint1" class="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint"/>
```

and here are the respective endpoints:

```
CXF_FIRST_ENDPOINT="cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint?{address=first_address}&serviceClass=com.service.class.first"
CXF_SECOND_ENDPOINT="cxf:bean:cxfEndpoint1?{address=second_address}&serviceClass=com.service.class.second"
```

Thanks,